# udp vs tcp packet dropping

Tags: tcp, udp, transport

If I send two packets via the net one is UDP packet and the other is TCP packet, which packet is more likely to reach its destination? I have been told that the TCP protocol is safer but this is because of it's "fail-safe" mechanism. But does it also mean that UDP packets are more likely to fall in the way?

I think it's related to the specific router implementation, because on one hand if a UDP packet disappears then both sides probably know it might happen and can afford to lose a packet or two but on the other hand if a TCP packet disappears then by it's "fail-safe" mechanism it will send another and the problem is solved, and TCP packet is much heavier.
I would like to have more solid answer for that question because i find this subject quite interesting.

Comment: You've already contradicted yourself. TCP has reliability features, so why is it up to the router implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a decision on which protocol to use for your application, you really need to look into both in more detail. Below is just an overview.

TCP is a stream protocol that provides several mechanisms that will deliver: a guaranteed delivery of data, in order. It will control the rate at which the data is sent (it will start transmitting slowly, then upping the speed auntil it reaches a rate that is sustainable by the peer). It will resend any data that was not received on the other side. To do that, you pay a price (for example the slow start, the need for acknowledging all data received etc.)

UDP on the other side is a "data chunk" (datagram) protocol and provides none of the checks of integrity / rate / order. It "compensates" by being (potentially) faster: you pump out data as fast as you can, the other side receives whatever it is able to catch, at full network speed in the extreme case. No guarantee of delivery or order of data arriving at the other side. They either receive the whole datagram or nothing.

Any decision one usually makes has nothing to do with the **possibility** of data being lost or not but the **criticality** of losing any of it. Video streaming is done via UDP many times since missing the occasional datagram is less critical than having a smooth image. File transmission cannot afford any data loss or inversions of data chunks, so TCP is the natural choice.

Apart form that question, remeber that the network protocol is only half your problem. The other half is coming up with your application protocol to interprest the bytes you are receiveing...